# WSAENETDOWN SocketException on a FEZ Spider kit

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpserver, .net-micro-framework

I'm trying to write a TCP server in .NETMF 4.3 for my FEZ Spider kit.

```
public partial class Program
{
    void ProgramStarted()
    {
        ethernetJ11D.NetworkInterface.Open();
        ethernetJ11D.UseStaticIP("192.168.0.8", "255.255.255.0", "192.168.0.1");
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7777);
        serverSocket.Bind(endPoint);
        serverSocket.Listen(10);

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.Print("Network up: " + ethernetJ11D.IsNetworkUp);//true
                Debug.Print("Network connected: " + ethernetJ11D.IsNetworkConnected);//true
                System.Net.Sockets.Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();//exception!
                new Thread(new Request(clientSocket).Process);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

The serverSocket.Accept method throws a SocketException with error code 10050. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page says it's WSAENETDOWN: Network is down. However the ethernetJ11D's properties state that the connection is up and I can ping the device without any problems. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

When I tried running the following client I got the same exception on the socket.Connect call.

```
ethernetJ11D.NetworkInterface.Open();
ethernetJ11D.UseStaticIP("192.168.0.8", "255.255.255.0", "192.168.0.1");
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.5"), 7777);
socket.Connect(endpoint);

Debug.Print("connected");
byte[] msg = new byte[] { 7, 77, 222 };
socket.Send(msg);
```

**EDIT 2**

I've tried to implement the UDP client instead. It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

1. Change `IPAddress.Any` to a static IP,e.g. `IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.8")`.
2. Delay Bind by adding `Thread.Sleep(3000)` right before it. It seems that the interface's network settings configuration takes some time.